# .licx need to be added to the main project?

Tags: c#

I have the following situation. I have a main project that's calling some other dll made by me (MainProject). One of the dll are using a third party dll that is licenced (DllA is using DllB - licenced). In the DllA project I've attached the file licences.licx as embedded resource.

Why can't I use the DllA from the main project? The licences.licx must be added to the main solution project? To the project that's generating the exe file??

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Per .NET licensing design you have to embed licenses to main application assembly (.exe in your case).

The easiest way to add .licx file to your main application is to create blank form, drop licenseable component onto the form and than remove form from your project.

Answer (score 1):

You need load the assembly with *.licx before you want use the licenced assembly.

You can:

Add references to the main project (and use it in code, otherwise compilere ignore the references)

-or-

Provide functionality through your assembly which was compiled with *.licx for specified licenced assembly.